# Show that $f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}f(a+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqIOd.png) is a picture of the problem
(sorry I have trouble typing the symbols).
Suppose f is holomorphic inside of a simple closed curve gamma. Show that
$$f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}f(a+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$$

I started by letting $z=a+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$
and $\frac{\mathrm d z}{d\theta}=\mathrm i\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}=\mathrm iz$ so $\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm iz}$. Then we have 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm iz}=
\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm i}\int \frac{f(z)}{z(z-a)}\mathrm dz
$$
I'm not entirely sure where to go from here. I looks like we should use the Cauchy integral formula, but I'm not sure how with the extra $z$ in the denominator.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the general version of Cauchy Integral Formula:

$$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi  i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} dz$$

For the first derivative you get exactly $(z-a)^2$ in the denominator.

**By the way** The problem is not true as stated. Since you need to integrate over a circle of radius 1, you need your function to be Analytic on a closed disk of radius at least 1, if your curve is too close to a, and the function is not analytic outside $a$ the problem is not true. Note that as given, the problem doesn't guarantee that $f(a+e^{it})$ even makes sense.

Comment: but I don't have (z-a)^2 in the denominator; I have z(z-a) which is why I am confused in the first place.

Comment: @Izelle Check again the step where you find $d \theta$. $e^{i \theta}$ is not $z$, it is $z-a$. So $\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm i(z-a)}$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That helps a lot!